# QGIS. Polygon doesn't repeat itself

Tags: qgis

In QGIS, I represent a polygon of the El Niño regions on the Pacific Ocean, as seen below:
[image: Regiones El Niño]
Now, what I need is that the regions of Oceania and East Asia are shown on the left side of the map, similar to this image:
[image: ej]

The shapefile of continents does not repeat itself, so how could it be done?
The idea is to avoid the use of secondary images like the OpenLayers plugin.

Answer (score 4):

A workaround below :

1. Duplicate the "world" layer. `Layer Menu` > `Duplicate layer` (or right-click on the layer)
2. Go to the duplicated layer properties. `Layer Menu` > `Layer properties` (or right-click on the layer, and by default, double-click on the layer)
3. In the symbology tab, as symbol type, choose `Geometry generator` ([doc link](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/style_library.html#the-geometry-generator))
4. Leave the `Polygon / Multi-polygon` symbol type and enter the formula :

   `translate($geometry, -360, 0)`
5. Give the same symbology to both layers and remove if necessary the borders (conflict for Antarctica, Fiji islands and Russia)

I assume there is no projection and coordinates are in degrees, but it's work even with a projection, just replace the `-360` part by the correct distance.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.

I did what you indicated, but from the Eurasia region it only shows Russia. Any suggestions?
By the way, I'm using WGS84 (EPSG: 4326)

Comment: It was a feature problem ... I don't know why (I think it's for rendering performances) but features with my solution are for non visual properties at their original places (show labels for understand). If you zoom out for see the two "worlds", you'll see all the features ... I advice you to use, in the toolbox, the translation tool for create a brand new layer (with false Lat/Lon coordinates but it will display all the features).

Comment: Ok. I will take your advice into account. Thank you very much for your help.